# WPF/XAML Bind DataGrid to a source that adds/removes columns and filters rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have an aplication for users to see and modify content in a file.
The contents are a collection of drawing sheet items (properties are Name, ID, etc), and a collection of groups called SheetSets (each group lists which sheets belong to it). The same sheet can belong to multiple SheetSets.

The users can filter which sheets are shown, and can add new SheetSets, and assign sheets to SheetSets. These changes will then update the content of the file where the content comes from.
For this, I'm using a DataGrid.

I think that I am having issues with data binding.
I build a DataTable from the content pulled from the file.
Then I bind to a DataView of the DataTable:

```
    public static void UpdateDataGrid(UIApplication uiApp, Ui ui)
    {
        UIDocument uidoc = uiApp.ActiveUIDocument;
        var viewSheetSets = new FilteredElementCollector(uidoc.Document).OfClass(typeof(ViewSheetSet)).ToElements();
        var viewSheets = new FilteredElementCollector(uidoc.Document).OfClass(typeof(ViewSheet)).ToElements();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataColumn sheetNumberColumn = dt.Columns.Add("Sheet Number");
        sheetNumberColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        DataColumn sheetNameColumn = dt.Columns.Add("Sheet Name");
        sheetNameColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        DataColumn sheetIdColumn = dt.Columns.Add("Sheet Id", typeof(Int32));
        sheetIdColumn.ReadOnly = true;

        foreach (ViewSheet viewSheet in viewSheets)
        {
            if (!viewSheet.IsPlaceholder)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["Sheet Number"] = viewSheet.SheetNumber;
                row["Sheet Name"] = viewSheet.Name;
                row["Sheet Id"] = viewSheet.Id.IntegerValue;
                foreach (ViewSheetSet ss in viewSheetSets)
                {
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains(ss.Name))
                    {
                        DataColumn column = dt.Columns.Add(ss.Name, typeof(Boolean));
                        column.ReadOnly = false;
                    }
                    else if (ss.Views.Contains(viewSheet))
                    {
                        row[ss.Name.ToString()] = true;
                    }
                    else { row[ss.Name.ToString()] = false; }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        if (ui.LblFilterText.Text != "")
        {
            if (ui.conditionComboBox.Text == "CONTAINS")
            {
                EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                         where row.Field<string>("Sheet Name").ToLower().Contains(ui.LblFilterText.Text.ToLower())
                                                         select row;

                ui.uiDV = query.AsDataView();
            }
            else if (ui.conditionComboBox.Text == "DOES NOT CONTAIN")
            {
                EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                         where !row.Field<string>("Sheet Name").ToLower().Contains(ui.LblFilterText.Text.ToLower())
                                                         select row;

                ui.uiDV = query.AsDataView();
            }
            else
            {
                ui.uiDV = dt.DefaultView;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                     where row.Field<string>("Sheet Name").Length > 0
                                                     select row;

            ui.uiDV = query.AsDataView();
        }

        ui.uiDataGrid.ItemsSource = ui.uiDV;
    }
```

Here's a screen capture of the resulting UI:

[image: Screen Capture]

The DataGrid does filter as intended.
I tested firing events when the checkboxes are changed, but sometimes they don't fire when they are supposed to.

While looking for answers, I noticed that most times DataGrids are bound in the XAML, instead of in code behind. But the examples I've seen were DataGrids bound to ObservableCollections of objects.

I have a feeling that I need to bind from XAML, but don't know the correct way to bind to the data I have, allowing the addition or removal of columns. Any help in understanding this would be much appreciated.

Here's the part of my XAML related to the DataGrid:

```
                        <DataGrid x:Name="uiDataGrid"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                  Grid.Row="3"
                                  Height="Auto" 
                                  CellEditEnding="uiDataGrid_CellEditEnding">
                             <DataGrid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Turquoise" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.Resources>
                        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is but there is no functional difference between setting the `ItemsSource` programmatically and bind it to a source property.

Comment: Hi mm8, thanks for replying.
Could you please point me to an example of a DataView being bound to a DataGrid?
I haven't done this before, and the examples I've found didn't involve DataViews.
Do I need to make the DataView a property?

Comment: Yes, you can only bind to public properties.